# update ajax on browsers back & refresh button is press

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, browser-history

Its my first web application  building with **jsp , jstl** using ajax as to make  music player play throughout the site.  i have many ajax req in single page .  when i click on that its works all fine but when ever i refresh it takes me to blank content page  in this code "Djpage.jsp" with out any content as requested in ajax i know as for url it will show but i researched a lot and tried  but its not working and when i click button it does not respond only url is changed .

Need help and  explanation how do i achieve this -

1. Show ajax data whenever refresh button is trigger.
2. Forward and backward button should work and show the ajax content.

Hope you get My problem

Below is on of my ajax req code -

```
$('li.box').on('click', function(){


      $(this).children("form").submit();
         var form =  $(this).children("form");
        var url = 'Djpage.jsp';
        var Djname = $(form).children('input[type=hidden][name=inputName]').val();
        $.get(url,{inputName:Djname},function(data){
                    $("#cssSlider").hide();
                  $("#tabscontainer").hide();

               $("#dj_loard").html(data);
                  $("#dj_loard").show();
                   var newTitle = $(data).filter('title').text();
                   document.title = newTitle;
                    window.history.replaceState({html:"Profilepage.jsp"},null, url);


        });        

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call functions (to make ajax request) on page load in order to fetch corresponding data of each section.
For e.g.,

```
$(function(){
// functions to be triggered on page load
  abc();
  xyz()
});
```

Comment: you mean to use it on "djpage.jsp" with a function  ?